# Parsing ampersands with expat fails. Invalid token?

Tags: c++, parsing, ampersand, expat-parser

I get an expat error when parsing specific characters only. Other HTML code is parsed just fine.
I'm using the UTF-8 library of expat *libexpatMT.lib* and I'm working with char and std::string in a wrapper. No wide chars etc. used.

```
// The ampersand leads to: Expat error: *not well-formed (invalid token)*
<a href="http://www.myurl.com?a=b&c=d">Link</a>
<span>Tom & Jerry</span>
<h1>K&auml;se</h1>
```

I'm confused why the ampersand can be an invalid token here, since it's used even within HTML entities like `&amp;`
Replacing the ampersands with `&amp;` or custom spacers doesn't work either.

Any suggestions? The ampersand is the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, you escape ampersand, even in entities. So the valid value is `<a href="http://www.myurl.com?a=b&amp;c=d">Link</a>`
Correct Web pages do that. Browsers are quite tolerant for the error you made, though.

Comment: This does not worke. It seems like I have to 'double escape' the values like: `&amp;auml;` for text like `<div>Tom&amp;Jerry</div>` Thanks!

Comment: There is something wrong there, check if there isn't a double conversion/unescaping occurring on your code, perhaps.